# Concentration in a solution

Tags: aqueous-solution

If I mix up 46.29 grams of Potassium Nitrate powder (KNO3) in 1000mL of water and then take 1 ml of that solution and put it into 1 gallon of water what will the ppm of "K" and "NO3" be separately.  For the 1000 mL solution and the 1 gallon of water.  A calculator I was using says it should add 7.5 ppm NO3 and 4.73 ppm of K to the 1 gallon.  If you could tell me how you came up with your answer that would be great.  I can come up with the 7.5 ppm but if I use the same logic for the K it does not work so I must not be doing it correctly.  Thank you for any help!

Comment: 1. There is no "K" or "NO3" in solution. Potassium nitrate dissociates completely to $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{NO3-}$ with equal ppm concentration on molar basis. 2. You didn't mention what basis you are calculating ppm for. 3. You cannot selectively pick different *amounts* of "K" or "NO3" (whatever these are) from one solution and transfer it to another. It seems to me the question needs improvements in terminology, notations and extra details.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I don't know how to answer what you have said.  This is for a liquid fertilizer.  I was using this calculator https://rotalabutterfly.com/nutrient-calculator.php and I input the numbers above.  I am just trying to figure out how they came up with the end results because it didn't seem correct compared to other solutions.

Comment: The calculator most likely intend ppm as mg in one kg of solution (at this concentration usually density is taken to be almost one, so most of the time ppm are used as mg/l. This can be fine or can be wrong, it just depends on concentration and purposes). Assuming you now the atomic mass involved, you must end up to the right values without calculator.